# Load a file into javascript and read first line

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, stream, arraybuffer

I have a 1GB file that I would like to load into a javascript buffer and then read the first line of it. I wasn't sure what the correct 'type' to use for this would be. For example, here is the pseudocode I have:

```
file = new FileBuffer('/user/me/Desktop/file.csv')
first_line = file.getline(0)
```

What would actually be the proper way to do this in javascript (`ArrayBuffer` or `SharedArrayBuffer` or `TypedArrayBuffer` ?), and what is the suggested 'buffer-type' to use for a utf-8 file with a known size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) is typically used for reading bytes of a file.  Reading with a streams API will be much more performant than reading the entire file into memory, especially with large files or files sent over a network.

**NodeJS:** see [Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream) and [`fs.createReadStream()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options). [`StringDecoder`](https://nodejs.org/api/string_decoder.html) could be used for converting bytes to strings.

**Web:** [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [Streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) could be used with small responses from [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests).  [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) could be used for converting bytes to strings.